# Django user_passes_test usage

Tags: python, django

I have a function-based view in Django:

```
@login_required
def bout_log_update(request, pk):
...
```

While it's protected from people who aren't logged in, I need to be able to restrict access to this view based on:
1. The user currently logged in
2. Which user created the object (referred to by pk)

It needs to be accessible only if the currently logged in user created the object being accessed, or is a superuser.

Can the standard @user_passes_test decorator accomplish this?  Or a custom decorator?  Or another method entirely?

I'd re-write it as a class-based view and use UserPassesTestMixin if I could, but I don't know that it's possible for this particular view.

Comment: You can't use `user_passes_test` because the test function only has access to the logged-in user, not the primary key. You would have to write a custom decorator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this quite easily with a custom decorator [based on `user_passes_test` source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/contrib/auth/decorators/#user_passes_test):

```
def my_user_passes_test(test_func, login_url=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME):
    """
    Decorator for views that checks that the user passes the given test,
    redirecting to the log-in page if necessary. The test should be a callable
    that takes the user object and returns True if the user passes.
    """

    def decorator(view_func):
        @wraps(view_func, assigned=available_attrs(view_func))
        def _wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
            # the following line is the only change with respect to
            # user_passes_test:
            if test_func(request.user, *args, **kwargs):
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            path = request.build_absolute_uri()
            resolved_login_url = resolve_url(login_url or settings.LOGIN_URL)
            # If the login url is the same scheme and net location then just
            # use the path as the "next" url.
            login_scheme, login_netloc = urlparse(resolved_login_url)[:2]
            current_scheme, current_netloc = urlparse(path)[:2]
            if ((not login_scheme or login_scheme == current_scheme) and
                    (not login_netloc or login_netloc == current_netloc)):
                path = request.get_full_path()
            from django.contrib.auth.views import redirect_to_login
            return redirect_to_login(
                path, resolved_login_url, redirect_field_name)
        return _wrapped_view
    return decorator
```

Note that just one line is changed from `test_func(request.user)` to `test_func(request.user, *args, **kwargs)` so that all arguments passed to the view are passed to the test function too.

Comment: Sorry, forgive me if this is a dumb question but I'm new to using decorators: How would this actually look when applied to view?

ie:

    @login_required
    @my_user_passes_test(something here to pass in pk somehow?)
    def bout_log_update(request, pk):
    ...

Comment: Ah, got it!  Regular users are now restricted to their own objects, and superuser can access all!  THANKYOU!